# installed kodak 3250 aio printer, but will not print

Tags: printing, kodak

I have installed drivers for the Kodak 325O AIO printer but it will not print...It stalls in the processing phase.  It will not print anything. Pictures, documents, anything...can anyone help with this.  Looking through the forums, there seem to be issues with Kodak and Ubuntu.
is there any fix for this that anyone knows of?

Comment: Which drivers did you install?

Comment: sudo apt-get install printer-driver-c2esp

Answer (score 0):

Install Kodak ESP AIO printer drivers package.

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-c2esp
```

Comment: I did that already.

Comment: I found this c2esp_25c-1_i386.deb but I get "E: Unable to locate package printer-friver-c2esp_25c-1_i386.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'printer-friver-c2esp_25c-1_i386.deb'" message